# Organização do código no controller codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou utilizando a HTML Table Class e as configurações da tabela são definidas através de uma array conforme documentação do próprio codeigniter http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/table.html?highlight=table#changing-the-look-of-your-table

Criei um método que só retorna essa array de configuração para melhorar a visualização do código.

Eu gostaria de saber se essa é a melhor abordagem ou existe algum outro modo que deixe o código mais organizado sem a necessidade de criar esse método?

```
function gera_arquivo()
{

    $this->table->set_template($this->define_template_table());
    $this->table->set_heading($this->define_cabecalho_tabela());
    $result = $this->model_acionamento->consulta_extracao($this->define_where_extracao());

    foreach ($result->result_array() as $row)
    {
        $dados_linha = [
            $row['nr_acionamento'],
            $row['dt_alarme'],
            $row['dt_abertura'],
            $row['dt_aceite'],
            $row['ds_status'],
            utf8_decode($row['setor_responsavel']),
            utf8_decode($row['ds_tipo']),
            utf8_decode($row['nm_usuario_abertura']),
            utf8_decode($row['nm_usuario_aceite']),
            utf8_decode($row['nm_usuario_finaliza']),
            $row['cd_operadora'],
            $row['cd_node'],
            $row['nr_oc'],
            $row['nr_outage'],
            $row['cod_baixa'],
            utf8_decode($row['ds_baixa']),
            $row['fc_confirmada_falta_energia'],
            $row['nr_protocolo'],
            $row['nm_concessionaria'],
            $row['dt_previsao'],
        ];
        $this->table->add_row($dados_linha);
    }
    $arquivo = 'extracao_monitoracao.xls';
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Content-Type: application/x-msexcel');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$arquivo}\"");
    echo $this->table->generate();
}

function define_template_table()
{
    $template = [
        'table_open' => '<table border=1>',
        'thead_open' => '<thead>',
        'thead_close' => '</thead>',
        'heading_row_start' => '<tr>',
        'heading_row_end' => '</tr>',
        'heading_cell_start' => '<th>',
        'heading_cell_end' => '</th>',
        'tbody_open' => '<tbody>',
        'tbody_close' => '</tbody>',
        'row_start' => '<tr>',
        'row_end' => '</tr>',
        'cell_start' => '<td>',
        'cell_end' => '</td>',
        'row_alt_start' => '<tr>',
        'row_alt_end' => '</tr>',
        'cell_alt_start' => '<td>',
        'cell_alt_end' => '</td>',
        'table_close' => '</table>'
    ];

    return $template;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rafael, se os valores de configuração não forem sofrer alteração é melhor você utilizar variável de classe ou um arquivo de configuração em *application/config*, ao invés de ter um método só pra retornar esses valores.

Comment: Tive problemas em implementar um arquivo de variáveis no config, mas vou tentar novamente. Obrigado Jonathan